# Why is the last li out of position?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to edit the navigation bar but the last li is a little down. Also when I hover over `English` there should be a drop down of other language. Please take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kKqZS/1/

What is causing a problem with the drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/ryAJ2/

There was a problem in the html code as well as a css selector for showing the nested ul

Comment: .no-js #main-nav li:hover > ul  -> #main-nav li:hover (in CSS)
and
the <nav id="main-nav"> node (see the fiddle) (in HTML)

Answer (score 2):

Remove those `&nbsp;` from your html

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/kKqZS/10/

So, i made that dropdown working there is a extra **li** inside the **parent li** of **countries dropdown**.

CSS has a class named `.no-js #main-nav li:hover > ul` so i removed **.no-js** as it is not used anywhere in HTML & move this complete class after `#main-nav ul ul` as its a good practice.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the position error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<li>
    <li class="top"><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=english">English</a</li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=russian">Russian</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=german">German</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

You can't nest li element inside li. Browser will close li tag automatically and understands your code like:

```
<li></li>
<li>English</li>
<ul>
        <li><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=russian">Russian</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=german">German</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: fixed it http://jsfiddle.net/kKqZS/7/